# Laravel4 duplicate / copy table row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm sure there has to be a quicker way to do the following. I wasn't able to find anything about how to save a laravel modal object as a new row without overwriting the existing item. Essentially, a simpler of my existing code:

```
$oldItem = Item::find(1);
$newItem = new Item;
$newItem->key = $oldItem ->key;
$newItem->name = $oldItem ->name;
$newItem->path = $oldItem ->path;
$newItem->save();
```

Instead, copying everything but the id of the row:

```
$oldItem = Item::find(1);
$newItem = $oldItem;
unset($newItem->id);
$newItem->save();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try

```php
$newItem = Item::find(1)->replicate()->save();
```

Comment: Is it possible to unset 1 value like $item->img

Comment: You can use:

`$newItem = Item::find(1)->replicate(); unset($newItem->img); $newItem->save();`

Comment: How can I get the id of the newly duplicated row? print_r($newItem) only returns 1 for some reason.

Comment: To get object break it up like so...

$newItem = Item::find(1)->replicate();
$newItem->save();
dd($newItem);